# How to upgrade npm inside a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I use the image `node:6.9` and I try to update to the version of npm from v3 to v4.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:6.9
MAINTAINER Philipp Kretzschmar <philipp.kretzschmar@gmail.com>
ENV TERM xterm-color
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
COPY docker/.docker-bashrc /root/.bashrc
RUN apt-get -qq update > /dev/null && \
    apt-get upgrade -qq > /dev/null && \
    apt-get install -qq rsync silversearcher-ag jq httpie vim s3cmd > /dev/null && \
    apt-get autoclean -qq
RUN npm update -g # this should upgrade npm!
RUN npm install typescript@2 -g --quiet > /dev/null
```

Yet it fails when running

```
npm update -g
```

stating:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-51-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "npm" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap
npm ERR! code EXDEV
npm ERR! errno -18
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/asap' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.asap.DELETE'
```

There's an [open github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9863) on npm already, and there the workaround is provided to use the `install.sh` script:

```
ADD https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh ./install.sh
RUN sh install.sh
```

which seems to download the npm 4.0.3 and and install it, yet now npm cannot be started from inside the container stating:

```
$ npm
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

What workaround that npm bug and and update npm version to a later version for a docker image?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269086/how-to-upgrade-npm-to-npm5-on-the-latest-node-docker-image

Answer (score 0):

It's either had to do with the running order. I added the update script as one of the first commands:

```
FROM node:6.9
MAINTAINER Philipp Kretzschmar <philipp.kretzschmar@gmail.com>
ENV TERM xterm-color
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ADD https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh ./install.sh
RUN sh install.sh
```

and it now works.

It also could have done with rebuilding the docker-container without using a cache. `docker build --no-cache`, yet it now works for me (and I don't know why):

```
$ npm -v
4.0.3
```