# How to upgrade npm to npm@5 on the latest node docker image?

Tags: docker, npm, alpine-linux

Locally, I have successfully installed npm@5 via:

```
$ npm install npm@5 -g
$ npm -v
$ 5.0.0
```

And locally, I can run the npm setup just fine (it's basically `npm i && tsc`)

```
$ npm run setup 
updated 102 packages in 3.499s
```

Yet now I also have a Dockerfile based upon the `node:7.10-alpine` image which breaks if I try to install `npm@5` there.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:7.10-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/hive-updater/
ENV LAST_UPDATED=2016-12-08 NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn TERM=xterm PATH="$PATH:/usr/hive-updater/node_modules/.bin"
RUN npm install npm@5 -g && npm -v
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run setup
CMD ["node"]
```

This will fail during `npm -v` with:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

How to get the latest npm on my docker container?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found out that the [node's alpine image ships with yarn](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/581eebd097343c9f1c1ceb5260cd2ec770410e29/7.10/Dockerfile#L34).

[Yarn](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360) is Facebook's npm replacement and you can use it to globally install npm@5:

```
RUN npm -v
RUN yarn global add npm@5
RUN npm -v
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run setup
```

(The version calls are superfluous and only to highlight that the upgrade works.)

And now it works:

```
Step 4/9 : RUN npm -v
 ---> Running in dca435fbec59
4.2.0
 ---> f6635e6c92a3
Removing intermediate container dca435fbec59
Step 5/9 : RUN yarn global add npm@5
 ---> Running in fac7216ccd91
yarn global v0.24.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "npm@5.0.0" with binaries:
      - npm
Done in 10.47s.
 ---> b6b2e0f3fc36
Removing intermediate container fac7216ccd91
Step 6/9 : RUN npm -v
 ---> Running in 38a9ee95b9f0
5.0.0
 ---> d1632fc97b7e
Removing intermediate container 38a9ee95b9f0
Step 7/9 : COPY ./ ./
 ---> b9b62f53ca48
Removing intermediate container e9dd065c022f
Step 8/9 : RUN npm run setup
 ---> Running in aec36af706d4

> hive-updater@1.0.0 setup /usr/hive-updater
> npm install --quiet && npm run build

added 102 packages in 5.156s

> hive-updater@1.0.0 build /usr/hive-updater
> tsc
```

So if you have npm below version 5 and its upgrade method breaks for you, install yarn to upgrade npm ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

*Sidenote*:

It might be better to just use yarn instead of npm@5. It still has a strong performance advantage.

Compare these runs, both cached:

```
yarn install v0.24.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.31s.
```

with npm@5:

```
npm install
updated 102 packages in 3.069s
```

I didn't know that `yarn` was already shipped with the alpine image.

Comment: I can verify this does seem to be a good workaround. I found these issues filed for it that might be related to this. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16891
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16837

Comment: This was a super handy answer.

Comment: This is very strange installing npm with yarn, but it works for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you for this, finally managed to update npm to version 5.5.1 on node 6.11, apparently the `npm install -g npm@latest` doesn't work, neither does reinstalling npm work